# apache RewriteRule from root to subdirectory missing links

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

i made a RewriteRule in my .htaccess to redirect the following pattern www.mysite.com/s/1 to www.mysite.com/site/core/gallery.php?s=1, the redirect works but the page loads with missing links how can i fix this

this is my rewrite rule:

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^s/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ /site/core/gallery.php?s=$1 [NC,L] # Handle scene requests

Comment: "but the page loads with missing links" <-- what do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely what you refer to with the expression "with missing links" is that objects referred to via links inside that page are not loaded once the page itself is loaded. This can have a number of reasons, since you do not provide any details we have to *guess*...

Most likely the reason is that your "links" are of wrong format, absolute instead of relative. Take a look at the format of the links that are not loaded. Probably they are either full urls including protocol scheme and server name or an absolut path (starting with a `/`). Since you redirect the request but most likely not requests to those embedded links things don't match.

Have a try changing the links to relative format (*not* starting with a leading `/`), so that the referenced objects can be found relative to the pages position in the namespace of the server.